# Why can't you drop a capability from the bounding set without CAP_SETPCAP?

Tags: linux, linux-capabilities

I have a Linux service that runs as a non-root user and holds a set of a few capabilities. When it starts, I want to fork off a child process. That child process should drop one of its capabilities (let's say `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE`). The idea is that in case there's a security vulnerability in the child process, an exploit will be less scary as it can't abuse that capability. The parent process is just a broker process, which retains `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` and will perform some actions on behalf of the unprivileged child process when it receives IPC messages from the child.

I'm able to remove this capability from every capability set in the child (inheritable, permitted, effective, and ambient) except for bounding. The call to `prctl(PR_CAPBSET_DROP)` of course requires `CAP_SETPCAP` (otherwise, you get `prctl(PR_CAPBSET_DROP): Operation not permitted`). I know that I can make my process spawn with `CAP_SETPCAP` initially and then remove it after I've changed the bounding set. My question is *why* does Linux not allow removing a capability from your bounding set unless you hold the `CAP_SETPCAP` capability? It seems odd that the Linux kernel prevents a process from reducing its own privileges.

Comment: This question about the design and rationale of Linux might be more appropriate for [linux.se].

Comment: FYI, this is in the description of the `CAP_SETPCAP` capability.

Comment: I suspect this may be a legacy of the earlier design where the bounding set was a system-wide setting, not per-process.

Comment: It was pretty subtle, but I read about it here: https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/thesendmailcapabilitiesissue

Comment: @tinkerer, maybe we can extract that into an answer? That definitely explains the design. Dropping the bounding set is privileged because calling setuid binaries would otherwise grant nearly full root.

Comment: I've expanded on the comment and made an answer of it. The write up is pretty dense, but hopefully I've included the key point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a write up here for why dropping capabilities from what root receives requires some privilege: https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/thesendmailcapabilitiesissue .

The example discussed there points out that if an unprivileged user can drop `CAP_SETUID` from the bounding set, then setuid-root programs can no longer drop privileges by changing UID from `root` to some other user.

If you can trick one of these applications into leaking a process running as `root`, minus that one capability, then you can probably use one of the other available capabilities for some exploit. Either that, or overwrite some system file owned by root and do something nasty to the OS.

As that write up mentions, this was used a long time ago to exploit `sendmail`. The kernel developers considered that exploit trivial enough to exploit, that dropping `root`'s capabilities needed to require some privilege.